# postgresql column alias methods

Tags: postgresql

I am attempting to make my sql more readable for my fellow develpoers. One method suggested in [aaron bertrands sql blog](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases) was to use the `=` instead of `AS`. I tried this in postgresql

```
    --doesn't work\/
    SELECT bar = my_table.foo
    FROM my_schema.my_table;
    --doesn't work/\

    --works\/
    SELECT my_table.foo bar
    FROM my_schema.my_table;
    --works/\

    --works\/
    SELECT my_table.foo AS bar
    FROM my_schema.my_table;
    --works/\
```

Is there another method where I would be able to list my alias first or perhaps a way to make my `SELECT` more readable. Incidentally, the method that `doesn't work` in postgresql will work in ms sql-server.

Comment: `bar = my_table.foo` is a boolean expression that compares the column `bar` to the column `foo`

Comment: you can use `:=` but i dont think it works
see: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/index.html

Comment: `ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":="
LINE 1: SELECT bar:= item.item_id`

Comment: AS has been an (optional) standard for quite a while and seems to work for most people. Are you looking for human readability or machine readability?

Comment: im looking for human readability